# Angular 2 Directive Renderer Not Working In Safari/IE

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 directive that has a host listener that sets the background-image css property like so:

```javascript
 this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background-image',`url(https://secure.miamibeachfl.gov/parking/content/images/${type}.png`);
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox but does not work in IE or Safari. I'm not sure if this is a compatibility issue with Angular and IE/Safari, or just a CSS issue. Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DjX9o8SBM53srb8zPdyW?p=info) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses.

```
  this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background', `url(https://secure.miamibeachfl.gov/parking/content/images/${type}.png)`);
```

I guess Chrome and Firefox will still be able to parse without it but Safari and IE can't.

Comment: Wow, my eyes were really playing tricks on me. I totally overlooked it because of it working in Chrome. Thanks